# Como tratar o erro 404 e 500 no vRaptor?

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, vraptor, página-de-erro

Já vi tutorial do vraptor4 ensinando a colocar esse erro no web.xml, pra redirecionar, o seguinte código xml:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Eu posso colocar esse código em qualquer local do web.xml que ele funciona normal? Ou devo fazer algo mais, pois pelas apostilas do vraptor da Caelum não está muito claro essa parte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você estiver falando do error-page da especificação de Servlets, até a versão 2.5, dentro da tag web-app (a tag principal do arquivo web.xml que fica dentro de WEB-INF) existe a possibilidade de você ter uma ou mais tags error-page, ex:

```
<!-- não encontrado -->
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<!-- erro interno -->
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/500.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Se for a partir do Servlet 3.0, você pode generalizar, fazendo:

```
<!-- qualquer erro -->
<error-page>
    <location>/minhaPaginaDeErro.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Aproveitando que estamos falando de paginas de erro, você pode ter acesso a objetos especiais (consegue até ver a stacktrace em caso de erro 500 por exemplo). Para mais mais detalhes, [veja este link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/bnahi/index.html).